# PHP and Jquery Multiple Images Crop (After Area Selection on Any One Image)

Tags: php, jquery, image-processing, crop

I am currently working on a project in PHP which involves uploading PDFs, converting them into images and then selecting a perimeter (area) on any one of the 4 uploaded PDFs (later images) as a reference, and finally crop those images all at once.

I have converted PDFs to images successfully (at a very high resolution), now what I need to do is to create a page say "Specify Perimeter", where I want to place any one of the four images as a reference for area/perimeter selection (since image would be of large size, a zoom functionality would also be required).

Once i have selected the area/perimeter, then I would click a button "Crop or Save Perimeter". And the server should take that perimeter and crop current as well as other 3 images with same perimeter.

Note: All images would be almost identical with same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a front-end tool you might find useful:
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

And a back-end tool you might find useful:
https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb